# A question on a $\omega_1$- Lindelöf space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ is $\omega_1$-Lindelöf space of countable tightness. Then how could I prove that in such space all free sequences are countable? Thanks ahead :)

A space is called $\omega_1$-Lindelöf space if for any open cover $\mathcal{U}$ with $\lvert \mathcal{U} \rvert = \omega_1$, then the space has countable subcover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Suppose that $\{x_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$ is a free sequence in $X$, and let $Y=\cl\{x_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$; $Y$ is $\omega_1$-Lindelöf. Let $y\in Y$; $t(X)=\omega$, so there is a countable $C\subseteq\{x_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$ with $y\in\cl A$. Since $A$ is countable, there is an $\eta(y)<\omega_1$ such that $A\subseteq\{x_\xi:\xi<\eta(y)\}$ and hence $y\in\cl\{x_\xi:\xi<\eta(y)\}$.

For $\eta<\omega_1$ let $F_\eta=\cl\{x_\xi:\eta\le\xi<\omega_1\}$, let $U_\eta=Y\setminus F_\eta$, and let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_\eta:\eta<\omega_1\}$. For each $y\in Y$ we have $y\notin F_{\eta(y)}$ and hence $y\in U_{\eta(y)}$, so $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $Y$ of cardinality $\omega_1$ and therefore has a countable subcover $\mathscr{U}_0$. Let $\eta=\sup\{\xi<\omega_1:U_\xi\in\mathscr{U}_0\}$; then $\eta<\omega_1$, and $U_\eta\supseteq\bigcup\mathscr{U}_0=Y$, which is absurd, since $x_\eta\notin U_\eta$.